# a good log monitoring tool with error notification?

Tags: logging, monitoring, alert

i know there are numberous log monitoring tools (with tail feature) out there and i have tried many of them. though they are all pretty good, i am looking for one specific feature which i haven't been able to find yet. All these log monitoring tools could add this feature easily.  The feature that i want is ..

- The way we can set filters and highlight rows. I want an add-on on this existing feature. I have multiple logs running real time. i cannot look at all the logs continuously. i want to use my filters to send a visual or email notification to me.a visual notification is something on the tab or a separate windows which says, this file has this word appeared.

let me knw if this is confusion.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [this tool](http://www.logfaces.com)? There are so called [triggers](http://www.moonlit-software.com/logfaces/web/images/screens/full/triggers.png) which will send you an email when certain log patterns are detected, the attachment will contain the log statements which caused the trigger to fire.

Answer (score 1):

if you need to monitor several logs and have the alerts from those logs report to one viewable web interface, you need to use Nagios. See http://www.logrobot.com for a screenshot. With Nagios, you can view the status of all your log checks and also receive email alerts when the thresholds you configured are breached.

Comment: Wow - am I supposed to wear some kind of special glasses to view that site properly or is it meant to look like that ;-)